Why is there a black foam inside the floaters used in Senseo machines?
Senseo machines have a floater in the water tank which indicates low water and stops the machine from running dry. This floater has a magnet inside, which due to humidity rusts, expands and blocks the floater from floating due to friction. Periodically the tank (yes, the tank! thanks Philips) has to be replaced.
Instead of replacing the tank, I want to replace the magnet, see iFixIt. This time I'll seal the floater tight with bicomponent (epoxy) glue, instead of just closing the lid of the floater, so that humidity won't get in.
The floater has the lid on the bottom side, and foam inside, above the magnet.
It's not clear to me the purpose of the foam, since the magnet is held in place by the lid.

Can I safely remove the foam?
I would achieve (very slightly) more buoyancy to the floater, so that I could put few beads of silica gel to extend the lifespan further.
Notes to the moderators
I think we should create a tag "repair" and one for "senseo" and apply them to this question.
Also, if this question is better suited to other sites, please let me know and I'll move or repost it.
